# How to Create a 10 min Timer that auto submit form in HTML using Javascript. (blank fields auto set value to 0 after submit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

It's been a while since I handle this jquery problem, but now, I am stuck with this issue where creating countdown timer in HTML using jquery or javascript to submit the form.

I've searched a lot on the internet, even on this site, but it didn't really help me the way my code was created. it was shown like this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <title>GHS Applicant Exam Tool</title>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

this one is for the script code of timer

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var total_seconds =60*10;
    var c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
    var c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds%60);
    function CheckTime(){
    document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML
    ='Time Left: ' + c_minutes + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds ' ;
    if(total_seconds <=0){
        setTimeout('document.quiz.submit()',1);
    } else{
        total_seconds = total_seconds -1;
        c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
        c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds&60);
        setTimeout("CheckTime()",1000);
    }}
    setTimeout("CheckTime()",1000);
    </script>

    <style>
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
```

This div style was the one for showing the countdown timer

```
  <div class="content">
   <div style="font-weight: bold" id="quiz-time-left"></div>
```

Return back to html code submit form

```
    <center><h3>GHS Applicant Assessment Tool</h3></center>

    <h5><p>This exam is an assessment tool to help us place you in the correct account.</p></h5>
    <p>* Required</p><br>

    <form name="quiz" id="myquiz" onsubmit="return validate()" method="post" action="/ghs/ghsadd.php" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">


    Last name*<br>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" ><br>

    First name*<br>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" ><br>

    Middle Initial<br>
    <input type="text" name="middle_initial" ><br><br>


    <p>Highest Educational Attainment*</p>

    <input type="radio" name="educ_attain" value="hsalsgrad"> High School Graduate / ALS Graduate<br>
    <input type="radio" name="educ_attain" value="shsgrad"> Senior High School Graduate<br>
    <input type="radio" name="educ_attain" value="undergrad1"> College Undergraduate 1 year<br> 
    <input type="radio" name="educ_attain" value="undergrad2"> College Undergraduate 2 years<br> 
    <input type="radio" name="educ_attain" value="undergrad3"> College Undergraduate 3 years<br> 
    <input type="radio" name="educ_attain" value="undergrad4"> College Undergraduate 4+ years<br>
    <input type="radio" name="educ_attain" value="collegegrad"> College Graduate<br>

    <hr>

    <p>Logic and Reasoning</p>

    <p>You will be given 5 minutes to complete this portion.</p><br>

    <p>The 4:25 P2P bus takes 1 hour and 45 minutes to arrive in 
    Trinoma. If Joseph takes this bus, what time will he arrive in 
    Trinoma? *</p>

    <input type="radio" name="logic1" value="0" required> 7:05 <br>
    <input type="radio" name="logic1" value="0" required> 6:25<br>
    <input type="radio" name="logic1" value="1" required> 6:10<br>
    <input type="radio" name="logic1" value="0" required> 5:55<br>

    <br>

    <p>Janine’s shoes cost $44.50, her pants cost $20.80 and her t-shirt
    cost $14.95. What is the total of her purchases? *</p>

    <input type="radio" name="logic2" value="0" required> 85.25<br>
    <input type="radio" name="logic2" value="1" required> 80.25<br>
    <input type="radio" name="logic2" value="0" required> 82.55<br>
    <input type="radio" name="logic2" value="0" required> 80.55<br>

    <input name="submit" name="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Submit"></input>

    </form>
```

The code was not that complicated as if you try to study HTML and javascript for the first time, it should so easy to understand. I didn't include all the questions which the input type was set as radio, text, text area, etc. as it could consume too much space here. Now, what I want to happen was when the countdown stops after 10 minutes, it will auto-submit the questionnaire in the `(action="/ghs/ghsadd.php)` new form. But right now, I was not working and just stops counting in 0 secs. I know there should be something to add or to change on the syntax of code to make this work. Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
function CheckTime(){
document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML
='Time Left: ' + c_minutes + ' minutes ' + c_seconds + ' seconds ' ;
if(total_seconds <=0){
    clearInterval(intervalVariable);

    $("#submit_button_id").click()

} else{
    total_seconds = total_seconds -1;
    c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds/60);
    c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds&60);
}}
var intervalVariable = setInterval(CheckTime,1000)
```

Comment: Should I just add it on the script tag? or replace it using this one?

Comment: replace this with urs.